# Ember can't access hasmany models in parent controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, controller

I would like to access child models in a parent controller to check if all the child models are completed. When I am at the lesson (parent) page for the first time the variables topicsTotal and topicsCompleted return 0 but when I go to a specific topic (child) page and then go back to this lesson page the variables topicsTotal and topicsCompleted are filled with the right numbers. It looks like the function allCompleted(); inside the controller is called before all the models are loaded. How can I fix this?

This is the lesson controller:

```
BecomeTjunaFish.LessonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  allCompleted: function() {
    var topicsTotal = this.get('topics.length'),
      topicsCompleted = this.get('topics').filterBy('isCompleted', true).get('length');
      console.log(topicsTotal);
      console.log(topicsCompleted);
      if (topicsTotal == topicsCompleted){
        $('.lessonBadge').addClass('completed');
      }
  }

});
```

This is the lesson model:

```
  BecomeTjunaFish.Lesson = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    progress: DS.attr('number'),
    img: DS.attr('string'),
    goal: DS.attr('string'),
    targetGroup: DS.attr('string'),
    prerequisites: DS.attr('string'),
    lesson_level: DS.attr('string'),
    lesson_time_indication: DS.attr('string'),
    lesson_url: DS.attr('string'),
    course: DS.belongsTo('Course', {async: true}),
    topics: DS.hasMany('Topic', {async: true}),
    lesson_authors: DS.hasMany('Authors', {async: true}),
    assignments: DS.hasMany('Assignment', {async: true})
  });

  BecomeTjunaFish.Lesson.FIXTURES = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'HTML Basis',
      progress: 50,
      img: 'images/html_badge.png',
      goal: 'HTML basis concepten beheersen',
      targetGroup: 'frontend developers in wording',
      prerequisites: 'geen',
      lesson_level: 'Beginner',
      lesson_time_indication: '45 minuten',
      course: 1,
      topics: [1,2,3],
      lesson_authors: [1, 2],
      assignments: [1]
    }
```

This is the lessonview:

```
BecomeTjunaFish.LessonView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function (){
        this._super();
        this.get('controller').allCompleted();
    }

});
```

Comment: have you tried using 'then' ? something like: this.get('topics').then(function(topics) {//all the code after var topicsTotal = this.get('topics.length') goes here, and you also have the 'topics' variable, so you can do topics.filterBy('isCompleted', true).get('length')})

Comment: Thanks fanta! It works and this is how the function looks like now: 

allCompleted: function() {
        this.get('topics').then(function(topics){
          var topicsTotal = topics.get('length'),
          topicsCompleted = topics.filterBy('isCompleted', true).get('length');
          if (topicsTotal == topicsCompleted){
              $('.lessonBadge').addClass('completed');
            }
        });

Comment: cool, glad you can continue with your project :)